# Icecast2 with Ices 0.4 - shutsdown questions

Tags: mp3, broadcast, icecast

My Icecast2 with Ices 0.4 shutsdown at the end of the playlist. How do i make it restart at top of playlist automatically? Also I use this command to make it start /usr/local/bin/ices -c /etc/ices/ices.conf -v , how do i make it start automatically upon server restart and - or after crash?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use "supervisor" to make sure something is running or gets restarted after stop or a crash.
Install with `apt install supervisor`, then create a config /etc/supervisor/conf.d/ices.conf with something like this:

```
[program:ices] 
 command=/usr/local/bin/ices -c /etc/ices/ices.conf -v
 user=icecast
 autostart=true
 autorestart=true
 stdout_logfile=/dev/null
 redirect_stderr=true
 stopsignal=QUIT
```

it should do the job.